# Django: Open a form from admin action

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to change some things inside this logic, so for now I'm only able to send a push notification to one user at the time and I'm trying to make that I would be able to select multiple users. So I have created an admin action which let's me to select some users and now I'm struggling about creating a form which would fulfill the users that I selected.

This is what I have now (Sending push notification to one user at the time).

[image]

Select users that I want to send the push notification.

[image]

This is my code:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('password',)}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('email', 'phone', 'companies',
                                         'active_company', 'avatar', 'completed_registration', 'language')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                                       'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined', 'work_hours_until', 'work_hours_from')}),
        (_('Terms and conditions agreement'), {'fields': ('agreement_date', 'agreement_text')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('phone',),
        }),
    )

    list_display = ['id', 'phone', 'email', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                    'date_joined', 'last_login']
    ordering = ('-id',)
    search_fields = ('email', 'phone')
    exclude = []

    actions = ('send_push_notification', )

    def send_push_notification(self, request, queryset):
        # Create some kind of form and logic..??
        queryset.update(is_staff=False) # This is just to test
```

Comment: What do you require this form for?

Comment: @dacx what do you mean? I just want to send a notification to multiple users, that's my solution to create a custom admin action